# SSIS Convert XML Task OperationResult from String to Int

Tags: ssis

I'm pulling the data from an XML node using an XPATH operation.  This is working fine, but instead of storing this data as a string, I'd like to convert it to an integer before storing it in a variable of type Int32.

I've tried doing it using the "Destination" expression, but I can't seem to find the code that will give me access to the result that's being passed out.  I could create two variables, and convert from one to another in a separate task, but this seems like a desperately hacky way of doing it.

Comment: perhaps post the code you have currently

Comment: There isn't any code as such.  This is all being done through the GUI.

There's an output from an XML Task (XPATH) operation, and an Int32 variable that I'd like to fill.  I can fill a String variable just fine, but have no idea how to convert the output before it's passed to the destination variable.

Comment: Agreed.  All I get is string, even if the XPath expression is a math operation that might return an Int32, or a == comparison that might return a boolean; it seems to always be a string regardless.  Any thoughts?